# Como controlar multithreading em paralelismo?

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Já tentei utilizar os **métodos** `wait()` com `notify` e até mesmo os **métodos depreciados** `stop()`, e não obtive sucesso.

**Possuo três (3) threads as quais são:**

> TankController
>
> FaucetFill
>
> FaucetEmpty

**O que eu estou tentando fazer é simplesmente o seguinte:**

> a) O TankController controla as threads FaucetFill e FaucetEmpty.
>
> b) A FaucetFill tem uma vazão de água de 10 litros á cada 150ms.
>
> c) A FaucetEmpty tem uma vazão de água de 30 litros á cada 150ms.

**Como funciona o TankController?**

> a) O controlador do tanque é responsável por abrir e fechar as torneiras.
>
> b) Quando o tanque atinge seu volume máximo, a torneira de enchimento é fechada e a torneira de esvaziamento é aberta.
>
> c) Quando o tanque estiver abaixo de 50% do seu volume a torneira de enchimento deverá ser aberta.
>
> d) Quando o volume de água ficar abaixo da torneira de esvaziamento, essa torneira deverá ser fechada.

**Qual problema que estou tendo?**

> Não consigo manipular corretamente as threads FaucetFill e FaucetEmpty dentro da thread TankController para poder abrir e fechar a torneira em sua determinada condição.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tank t = new TankWater();
        FaucetFill ff = new FaucetFill(t);
        FaucetEmpty fe = new FaucetEmpty(t);
        TankController tc = new TankController(t, ff, fe);
    
        ff.start();
        fe.start();
        tc.start();
    }

}
```

**TankController.java**

```
public class TankController extends Thread {
    private final TankWater tank;
    private final FaucetFill ff;
    private final FaucetEmpty fe;
    
    public TankController(Tank t, FaucetFill ff, FaucetEmpty fe) {
        this.tank = t;
        this.ff = ff;
        this.fe = fe;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("TANK-CONTROLLER RUNNING!");
        
        // CÓDIGO DE CONTROLE DAS TORNEIRAS
    
    }

}
```

**FaucetFill.java**

```
public class FaucetFill extends Thread {
    private final TankWater tank;
    private final int timer = 150;
    private int litersWater = 10;
    private boolean isStarted;
    
    public FaucetFill(Tank t) {
        this.tank = t;
    }
    
    public void setIsStarted(boolean state) {
        this.isStarted = state;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(this.isStarted) {
            System.out.println("FAUCETFILL RUNNING");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(this.timer);
            this.tank.setAmountWater(this.litersWater);
        }
     
    }
}
```

**FaucetEmpty.java**

```
public class FaucetEmpty extends Thread {
    private final TankWater tank;
    private final int timer = 150;
    private int litersWater = 30;
    private boolean isStarted;
    
    public FaucetEmpty(Tank t) {
        this.tank = t;
    }
    
    public void setIsStarted(boolean state) {
        this.isStarted = state;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(this.isStarted) {
            System.out.println("FAUCETEMPTY RUNNING");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(this.timer);
            this.tank.removeWater(this.litersWater);
        }
        
    }

}
```

**TankWater.java**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TankWater {
    private final int maximumCapacity = 2000;
    private int amountWater = 0;
    
    public int getAmountWater() {
        return amountWater;
    }
    
    public void setAmountWater(int amountWater) {
        if(this.getPercentageWater() != 100)
            this.amountWater += amountWater;
    }
    
    public void removeWater(int quantity) {
        if(this.getAmountWater() - quantity >= 0)
            this.setAmountWater(this.getAmountWater() - quantity);
    }
    
    public double getPercentageWater() {
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(this.maximumCapacity);
        BigDecimal rate  = new BigDecimal(this.getAmountWater());
        BigDecimal percentage = rate.divide(value).multiply(new BigDecimal("100"));
        
        return percentage.doubleValue();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thiago, você pode como alternativa implementar o padrão singleton em seu main e suas threads monitorarem a classe principal, seria meio que um controle invertido, acredito ter maneiras melhores de contornar, mas funciona na prática.

Comment: `TankWater` não estende `Thread`, porque você diz que ele é uma Thread? Pelo que vejo ele é acessado por Threads. Note também que o seu `setAmountWater(int amountWater)` não protege o tanque de "transbordar" (mesmo se o tanque estiver vazio e você passar como argumento 3000 o tanque ficará com 3mil litros, bem acima da capacidade e portanto em um estado inconsistente); esse problema também vai ocorrer se ele estiver com uns 1995 litros e a `FaucetFill` adicionar +10 litros, ele vai para 2005 litros.

Comment: @Douglas sobre o TankWater está corrigido, realmente ele não é uma Thread. As outras questões eu corrigi e consegui o algoritmo da resposta que dei abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui manipular o **paralelismo** com o **multithreading** e todas as informações citadas em minha pergunta. Segue abaixo o meu código e uma animação do `output`.

**Output [Animação]**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Console.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Console {
    private static final ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls");

    public static void clearScreen() {  
        try {
            process.inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        } catch(IOException | InterruptedException e) {}  
    } 
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        TankWater tw = new TankWater();
        FaucetFill ff = new FaucetFill(tw);
        FaucetEmpty fe = new FaucetEmpty(tw);
        TankWaterController twc = new TankWaterController(tw, ff, fe);

        System.out.println("Para iniciar a simulaÃ§Ã£o tecle ENTER ou CTRL+C para finalizar");
        input.nextLine();

        twc.init();
        input.nextLine();
    }

}
```

**FaucetEmpty.java**

```
public class FaucetEmpty extends Thread {
    private final TankWater tankWater;
    private boolean isOpen;
    private int literOfWater = 30;
    private long timer = 150;

    public FaucetEmpty(TankWater tw) {
        this.tankWater = tw;
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    public synchronized void open() {
        this.isOpen = true;
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isOpen() {
        return this.isOpen;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!interrupted()) {
            if(this.isOpen)
                this.tankWater.removeWater(this.literOfWater);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**FaucetFill.java**

```
public class FaucetFill extends Thread {
    private final TankWater tankWater;
    private boolean isOpen;
    private int literOfWater = 10;
    private long timer = 150;

    public FaucetFill(TankWater tw) {
        this.tankWater = tw;
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    public synchronized void open() {
        this.isOpen = true;
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isOpen() {
        return this.isOpen;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!interrupted()) {
            if(this.isOpen)
                this.tankWater.fillWater(this.literOfWater);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Scene.java**

```
public class Scene {
    private boolean tankMatrix[][];
    private final TankWater tankWater;
    private final FaucetFill faucetFill;
    private final FaucetEmpty faucetEmpty;

    public Scene(TankWater tw, FaucetFill ff, FaucetEmpty fe) {
        this.tankMatrix = new boolean[10][20];
        this.tankWater = tw;
        this.faucetFill = ff;
        this.faucetEmpty = fe;
    }

    public synchronized void updateTankWater() {
        int volumeWater = this.tankWater.getCurrentWaterVolume() / 10;

        for(int line = 9; line >= 0; line--) {
            for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
                if(volumeWater > 0) {
                    this.tankMatrix[line][column] = true;
                    volumeWater--;
                } else {
                    this.tankMatrix[line][column] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(this.faucetFill.isOpen()) {
            for(int line = 9; line >= 0; line--)
                this.tankMatrix[line][8] = true;
        }
    }

    public synchronized void printScene() {
        int line;

        Console.clearScreen();
        System.out.println(this.tankWater.getCurrentWaterVolume());
        System.out.println("----------+");
        System.out.println("oooooooooo|");
        System.out.println("--------+o|");
        System.out.println("        |o|");

        if(this.faucetFill.isOpen()) {
            System.out.println("        +o+");
            System.out.println("         o");
        } else {
            System.out.println("        +-+");
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(line = 0; line < 5; line++) {
            System.out.print("|");

            for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
                System.out.print(this.tankMatrix[line][column] ? 'o' : ' ');
            }

            System.out.println("|");
        }

        System.out.print("|");

        for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
            System.out.print(this.tankMatrix[line][column] ? 'o' : ' ');
        }

        System.out.println("+------+");
        line++;
        System.out.print("|");

        for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
            System.out.print(this.tankMatrix[line][column] ? 'o' : ' ');
        }

        System.out.println(this.faucetEmpty.isOpen() ? "ooooooo|" : "|oooooo|");
        line++;
        System.out.print("|");

        for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
            System.out.print(this.tankMatrix[line][column] ? 'o' : ' ');
        }

        System.out.println("+----+o|");
        line++;
        System.out.print("|");

        for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
            System.out.print(this.tankMatrix[line][column] ? 'o' : ' ');
        }

        if (this.faucetEmpty.isOpen()) {
            System.out.println("|    +o+");
        } else {
            System.out.println("|    +-+");
        } 

        line++;
        System.out.print("|");

        for(int column = 0; column < 20; column++) {
            System.out.print(this.tankMatrix[line][column] ? 'o' : ' ');
        }

        System.out.print('|');

        if(this.faucetEmpty.isOpen()) {
            System.out.print("     o");
        }

        System.out.print("\n+--------------------+");

        if(this.faucetEmpty.isOpen()) {
            System.out.println("     o");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nPara parar a simulaÃ§Ã£o aperte a tecla CTRL+C.");
    }


}
```

**TankWater.java**

```
public class TankWater {
    private final int maximumWaterVolume = 2000;
    private int currentWaterVolume = 0;

    public synchronized int getCurrentWaterVolume() {
        return this.currentWaterVolume;
    }

    public synchronized void fillWater(int litersOfWater) {
        this.currentWaterVolume += litersOfWater;
    }

    public synchronized void removeWater(int litersOfWater) {
        if(this.currentWaterVolume >= litersOfWater)
            this.currentWaterVolume -= litersOfWater;
        else 
            this.currentWaterVolume = 0;
    }
}
```

**TankWaterController.java**

```
public class TankWaterController extends Thread {
    private final TankWater tankWater;
    private final FaucetFill faucetFill;
    private final FaucetEmpty faucetEmpty;  
    private final Scene scene;

    public TankWaterController(TankWater tw, FaucetFill ff, FaucetEmpty fe) {
        this.tankWater = tw;
        this.faucetFill = ff;
        this.faucetEmpty = fe;
        this.scene = new Scene(this.tankWater, this.faucetFill, this.faucetEmpty);
    }

    public void init() {
        this.faucetFill.start();
        this.faucetEmpty.start();
        start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!interrupted()) {
            if(this.tankWater.getCurrentWaterVolume() <= 1000)
                this.faucetFill.open();
            if(this.tankWater.getCurrentWaterVolume() >= 2000) {
                this.faucetFill.close();
                this.faucetEmpty.open();
            }

            if(this.tankWater.getCurrentWaterVolume() <= 600)
                this.faucetEmpty.close();

            this.scene.updateTankWater();
            this.scene.printScene();
        }
    }
}
```